# Unable to navigate using storyboards in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

[image]`"PrepareForSegue(UIKit.UIStoryboardSegue, Foundation.NSObject)'` is marked as an override but `no suitable method found to override"` is the error i am getting when i trying to write the below code

```
 public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
                {
                    if (segue.Identifier == "detailSegue") {

                        var dtlVC = segue.DestinationViewController as DetailVC;

![Unable to Override][2]


                }
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That class must be classed from UIViewController or UITableViewController. If it's not a view controller subclass then it will not find the super class definition for overriding and hence the error.

Comment: Thank for the answer but What I am doing is trying to navigate on RowSelection in a TableViewSource Subclass. So in this case how should I go ahead as my class is not a subclass of UIViewController neither is it a subclass of UitableViewConmtroller...?

Comment: Use delegation. Add a custom delegate property in your TableViewSource subclass to inform the delegate that rowSelection happened. Set the view controller that displays the table as the delegate. Implement the protocol method in the view controller to perform some navigation when that method is called through the delegation.